# android get value from all fragment tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

i had declare framgmentActivity like below:

```
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("basic").setIndicator("Basic",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)),BasicProductFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("taxes").setIndicator("Taxes",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)),TaxesProductFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("price").setIndicator("Price",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)),PriceProductFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("stock").setIndicator("Stock",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)),StockProductFragment.class, null);
```

Now in all frament i had declare two or three edittext now in this activity, i want to get data from that all edittext from diffrent frangment tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A singleton class could help solve your problem.

```
public class GlobalApp {
    private static GlobalApp instance = new GlobalApp();

    private GlobalApp() {}

    public static GlobalApp getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public Details details = new Details ();

}
```

Then use in your Fragment class like this..

```
GlobalApp.getInstance().details.setSomeData("something");
```

Now you can get all the values which are changed in those fragment in your mainActivity

```
 GlobalApp.getInstance().details.getSomeData();
```

I have given the same answer for another question which has some relation to this.

[Communicative Between Fragments on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040649/communicative-between-fragments-on-android/17041161#17041161)

Comment: sorry i cannot understand about this GlobalApp class

Comment: @PintuCorna: Its a Singleton Pattern, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: ok but in my activity how can i get value from all edittext,, i had Basic fragment tab with two edittext, Taxes fragment tab with three edittext now in my this Acvitiy i want to store all edittext value in database so in my activity how can i get using this globalApp class.

Comment: You should use the GlobalApp.getInstance().Object for storing/getting values, you should send GlobalApp.getInstance().Object to your DB. you can use the GlobalApp.getInstance().Object then anywhere.

Comment: but in my fragment had not any button so on editext how can i set value to this gloabalapp

Comment: You enter some value in EditText, how do you save it to DB.

Comment: you can set the value to your GlobalApp Instance on Change of EditText Field.

Comment: Thanks for this first i cannot understant this but when i impletement it and modify small change it work.. Thanks a lot